# setExpressCheckout and SSL/TLS error

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm  trying to develop a simple application that will enable users to purchase services off a website through the Paypal API. This application is running on ASP.NET with C#.

I have had very little luck trying to get the Paypal API to co-operate. The method I'm calling is SetExpressCheckout with all the appropriate variables.

I did my research and discovered that since I'm testing in Localhost, it may affect Paypal's ability to communicate with the application. So the next thing I tried was accessing my application through an open port and a publicly accessible IP address, but the same error occurs on the call to SetExpressCheckout.

Here is the error:

```
Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Source Error: 


Line 1790:        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SetExpressCheckoutResponse", Namespace="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI")]
Line 1791:        public SetExpressCheckoutResponseType SetExpressCheckout([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI")] SetExpressCheckoutReq SetExpressCheckoutReq) {
Line 1792:            object[] results = this.Invoke("SetExpressCheckout", new object[] {
Line 1793:                        SetExpressCheckoutReq});
Line 1794:            return ((SetExpressCheckoutResponseType)(results[0]));

Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\anan_p2\730602d6\31a8d74e\App_WebReferences.c8vgyrf8.2.cs    Line: 1792
```

I've also tried generating certificates using OpenSSL and uploading them to the Paypal account's encrypted seller option but still no effect.

Thank you very much for reading through my question!

Update: As requested here is the code being used.

```
        String hostingOn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["default_site_url"];
        reqDetails.ReturnURL = hostingOn + "marketplace_confirm.aspx";
        reqDetails.CancelURL = hostingOn + "marketplace.aspx";
        reqDetails.NoShipping = "1";
        reqDetails.ReqConfirmShipping = "0";

        reqDetails.OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType()
        {
            currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.CAD,
            Value = payment_amt.Value,
        };

        SetExpressCheckoutReq req = new SetExpressCheckoutReq()
        {
            SetExpressCheckoutRequest = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType()
            {
                Version = UtilPayPalAPI.Version,
                SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = reqDetails
            }

        };

        PayPalAPIAASoapBinding paypal = new PayPalAPIAASoapBinding();

        paypal.SetExpressCheckout(req);
```

I am also using the https://api-aa-3t.paypal.com/2.0/ url for accessing the API

Comment: Can you post the actual code that you are using to connect instead of the Error there could also be several other issues I will post below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably connecting to api.paypal.com or api.sandbox.paypal.com, and not sending along your API certificate. The API certificate is a client SSL certificate used to complete the SSL chain.

If you don't have or are not using an API certificate, you should connect to api-3t.paypal.com or api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com for Live or Sandbox respectively.

Comment: The problem seems to be that while I was using the correct server, I wasn't calling it properly. I went to the paypal site and generated the paypal functions automatically and using the included ShortcutExpressCheckout method, I was able to successfully get a token. The generator is here: https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/main.php

Comment: paypal-labs.com home page currently says 'We are currently working on a new website', the link above returns an empty page.

Try this one:
https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/

The C# wizard seems to run Ok, I've not tried the code as yet.

Answer (score 19):

Since early 2016, Paypal started requiring TLS 1.2 protocol for communications in the Sandbox, and will enforce it for the live environment starting June 17. See [here](https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/) for reference.

In most .NET applications TLS 1.2 will come **disabled by default**, and therefore you'll need to enable it.

You need to add the following line, for example, at the beginning of you `Application_Start` method:

```
public class Site : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        // other configuration
    }
}
```

Comment: God bless you! You saved my day. :)

Comment: For those using older versions of MVC (3) or the .NET Framework (<4.5) you can achieve the above by using:

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;`

Answer (score 2):

I've been working with a PayPal (NVP/Signature) Express Checkout integration and have been hit with this SSL/TLS error.

Nothing I did seemed to get around it but then I found the following code to add above my request. For reference, I'm using MVC3/.NET 4 so Tls1.2 isn't available to me by default (like in .NET 4.5 +). This first three lines of this code gets around that. I hope it helps people!

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;

var url = "https://[paypal-api-url]/nvp";
var uri = new Uri(url);
var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
var requestData = encoding.GetBytes(data);

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = (300 * 1000); 
request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
}

var response = request.GetResponse();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot that really helps me.

For reference here is my code for establishing the interface in VB.NET

```
  'Create a service Binding in code
                            Dim ppEndpointAddress As New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/")
                            Dim ppBinding As New System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport)

                            Dim ppIface As New PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient(ppBinding, ppEndpointAddress)

                            Dim ppPaymentReq As New PayPalAPI.DoDirectPaymentReq()

                            ppPaymentReq.DoDirectPaymentRequest = ppRequest
```