# Paypal Sandbox MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, paypal-sandbox

I was testing the paypal API for a website I'm making. Everything was working fine last night, but when I ran it again today, I received the following error:

> Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'api-aa.sandbox.paypal.com'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Had the same. Try to use http://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/ instead. 
It helped me. I found it here: [setExpressCheckout and SSL/TLS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681135/setexpresscheckout-and-ssl-tls-error)

> If you don't have or are not using an API certificate, you should connect to api-3t.paypal.com or api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com for Live or Sandbox respectively.

Comment: I called up paypal and they let me know that their latest API had errors in them. wherever it said 

    api.sandbox.paypal.com or api-aa-.sandbox.paypa.com

Needs to be switched to read:

    api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com or api-aa-3t.sandbox.paypa.com

So you were pretty much correct, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I have been battling this same issue for several hours now; After writing the PayPal Express checkout integration using the SOAP API with Signing over year ago it was put on the back burner (all unit test passing at the time). I come  back to it today to the error:

> Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com'

After much research I have isolated the issue in our instance being down to the default `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` value being `System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls`, updating this to `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` fixed the issue.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```